# How do I find the predominant letters in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check for each position in the string what is the character that appears most often on that position. **If there are more of the same frequency, keep the first one.** All strings in the list are guaranteed to be of identical length!!!

I tried the following way:

```
print(max(((letter, strings.count(letter)) for letter in strings), key=lambda x:[1])[0])
```

But I get: `mistul` or `qagic`

And I can not figure out what's wrong with my code.

My list of strings looks like this:

Input: `strings = ['mistul', 'aidteh', 'mhfjtr', 'zxcjer']`

Output: `mister`

Explanation: On the first position, **m** appears twice. Second, **i** appears twice twice. Third, there is no predominant character, so we chose the first, that is, **s**. On the fourth position, we have **t** twice and **j** twice, but you see first **t**, so we stay with him, on the fifth position we have **e** twice and the last **r** twice.

Another examples:

Input: `['qagic', 'cafbk', 'twggl', 'kaqtc', 'iisih', 'mbpzu', 'pbghn', 'mzsev', 'saqbl', 'myead']`

Output: `magic`

Input: `['sacbkt', 'tnqaex', 'vhcrhl', 'obotnq', 'vevleg', 'rljnlv', 'jdcjrk', 'zuwtee', 'xycbvm', 'szgczt', 'imhepi', 'febybq', 'pqkdfg', 'swwlds', 'ecmrut', 'buwruy', 'icjwet', 'gebgbq', 'djtfzr', 'uenleo']`

Expected Output: `secret`

Some help?

Comment: Looks like this is a good solution to my question : `print ''.join([max(i, key=i.count) for i in (zip(*strings))])`

Comment: Bummer that [`statistics.mode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode) doesn't have any way to specify behaviour for non-unique result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally a use case for [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) :-)

If you like cryptic code, it *could* even be done in one statement:

```py
def solve(strings):
    return ''.join([max([(letter, letters.count(letter)) for letter in letters], key=lambda x: x[1])[0] for letters in zip(*strings)])
```

But I prefer a more readable version:

```py
def solve(strings):
    result = ''
    # "zip" the strings, so in the first iteration `letters` would be a list
    # containing the first letter of each word, the second iteration it would
    # be a list of all second letters of each word, and so on...
    for letters in zip(*strings):
        # Create a list of (letter, count) pairs:
        letter_counts = [(letter, letters.count(letter)) for letter in letters]
        # Get the first letter with the highest count, and append it to result:
        result += max(letter_counts, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
    return result

# Test function with input data from question:
assert solve(['mistul', 'aidteh', 'mhfjtr', 'zxcjer']) == 'mister'
assert solve(['qagic', 'cafbk', 'twggl', 'kaqtc', 'iisih', 'mbpzu', 'pbghn',
              'mzsev', 'saqbl', 'myead']) == 'magic'
assert solve(['sacbkt', 'tnqaex', 'vhcrhl', 'obotnq', 'vevleg', 'rljnlv',
              'jdcjrk', 'zuwtee', 'xycbvm', 'szgczt', 'imhepi', 'febybq',
              'pqkdfg', 'swwlds', 'ecmrut', 'buwruy', 'icjwet', 'gebgbq',
              'djtfzr', 'uenleo']) == 'secret'
```

**UPDATE**

@dun suggested a smarter way of using the `max()` function, which makes the one-liner actually quite readable :-)

```py
def solve(strings):
    return ''.join([max(letters, key=letters.count) for letters in zip(*strings)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.Counter()` is a nice strategy here. Here's one way to do it:

```
from collections import Counter

def most_freq_at_index(strings, idx):
  chars = [s[idx] for s in strings]
  char_counts = Counter(chars)
  return char_counts.most_common(n=1)[0][0]

strings = ['qagic', 'cafbk', 'twggl', 'kaqtc', 'iisih', 
           'mbpzu', 'pbghn', 'mzsev', 'saqbl', 'myead']

result = ''.join(most_freq_at_index(strings, idx) for idx in range(5))
print(result) 
## 'magic'
```

Comment: You're sure your outout is 'magic' ? It shows me for your code, 'magbc'

Comment: @dun.py yeah... because you're using 2.7 and until 3.6 - insertion orders in dictionaries (and thus `collections.Counter`) couldn't be guaranteed...

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more manual without the magic of Python libraries you can do something like this:

```
def f(strings):
    dic = {}
    for string in strings:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            word_dic = dic.get(i, { string[i]: 0 })
            word_dic[string[i]] = word_dic.get(string[i], 0) + 1
            dic[i] = word_dic
    largest_string = max(strings, key = len)
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(largest_string)):
        result += max(dic[i], key = lambda x : dic[i][x])
    return result
```

```
strings = ['qagic', 'cafbk', 'twggl', 'kaqtc', 'iisih', 'mbpzu', 'pbghn', 'mzsev', 'saqbl', 'myead']
f(strings)
'magic'
```